# Jupyter is not starting with my environemnt

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter, virtual-environment

So for the first problem in my life I have this problem. I activate my venv through:

```bash
source venv/bin/activate
```

I then install jupyter with

```bash
pip install jupyter
```

Now when in a notebook and I do

```py
sys.executable
```

I get

```bash
./bin/python3
```

But this is not my environemnt! When I enter python through terminal and do the same I get:

```bash
/home/user/.../venv/bin/python3
```

Additionally, I'm missing all my libraries and stuff...

Comment: can you show how you're starting up your jupyter notebook? Also, what does `os.getcwd()` show?

Comment: Did you search for this?  This is a common question.  https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/